# Laravel query isn't allowing me to query and where inside orWhere

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I have laravel and laravel-livewire. Maybe it's overkill but I wanted to limit results to 10 or so and then have those 10 results filter to new results as the person typed out a name or phone number. The query works perfectly fine if I use just one of the statements. If I get rid of the phone and leave name it works, the same for getting rid of name and leaving phone. But if I have both like below it doesn't work. In the debug bar I see the query and it looks like what it should, but I don't get any results once I start typing.

```
$customers = DB::table('customers')->where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('phone', 'like', '%'.$this->phone.'%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$this->name.'%');
        })
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

outputs query in debug bar

```sql
select * 
from `customers` 
where `user_id` = 12 
  and (`phone` like '%%' or `name` like '%%') 
limit 10`
```

Comment: Can `$this->phone` and `$this->name` both have values?

Comment: Try checking if "$this" has value before the query. and insure that "$this" has both phone and name in it.

if $this exists and has values, then maybe you can try smth like this as a test:
$that = $this
......
->where(function($query) use ($that) {

Comment: Both variables can have values, in fact the way it is it would be impossible for them both to not eventually. Both of them are updating in values just fine, @kenyalang's answer solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing it like this

```
$customers = DB::table('customers')->where('user_id', auth()->id())
->where(function($query) {
    $query->when(!is_null($this->phone), function ($q) {
           $q->where('phone', 'like', '%'.$this->phone.'%')
        })
        ->when(!is_null($this->name), function ($q) {
           $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->name.'%')
        });
    })
->limit(10)
->get();
```